# Cant override jQuery UI autocomplete renderItem method multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

It overrides properly in the first autocomplete found, but do nothing with the rest. 
Instead it loads the original _renderitem method that you can see at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L449.

```
$(".someClassWithMultipleItemsOnDOM").autocomplete({
        delay:500,
        minLength:2,
        source:path"
        .....   
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a workaround for this problem:

```
var autoc = {
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 2,
    source: path,
    .....   
};

var renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br/>" + item.desc + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};

$(".someClassWithMultipleItemsOnDOM").each(function (i) {
     $(this).autocomplete(autoc).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = renderItem;
}
```

Comment: It's a [JavaScript Object Literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php). Obviously you'd have to get rid of the '....' and the last comma for this example to work.

Comment: @tomc - you just saved me HOURS of extra work. Do the `jquery-ui` folks now that a workaround is needed for multiple autocomplete elements?

Answer (score 10):

You can override _renderItem

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) { ... };
```

Comment: It is recommended to do that way?

Comment: It's a way to do it. Neither recommended nor not recommended.