# (jquery?) Autocomplete for display in two or more lines?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, lines

I am using since a couple of years an ajax autocomplete script which proposes preselected keywords for the search. Now, I'd like to extend it to actually display the names of the (data) variables, which can however extend to 100 characters. Thus, the results need to be displayed in the dropdown box in multiple (at least two) lines.

I found a jquery autocomplete plugin which does that: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin.

And this one: http://www.web2ajax.fr/2008/02/03/facebook-like-jquery-and-autosuggest-search-engine/

Otherwise, not too much stuff out there, is my impression.

There is one other challenge: I would like that the autocomplete not only searches at the beginning of the name but in any part of the field. (Which, I guess, is any way a server side thing, right?)

Can you recommend any stable and not-too-fancy solution perhaps?

Thanks for any hints and recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery itself have autocomplete widget. It will works like as you expecting. Check this links.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

http://jqfaq.com/category/widgets/autocomplete/

Comment: Thx for that. Yes, I know that one. But I haven't seen any example that uses jQuery-autocomplete and is able to display the dropdown in mutliple lines.

Comment: Check this links. I think this will help you.
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-html-in-autocomplete
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180246/cant-override-jquery-ui-autocomplete-renderitem-method-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it using the **_renderItem**  method of jquery ui:
Note that I had to break a long paragraph into lines with a width of 50 characters.

```
$("#id_info").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            timeout: 5000,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                term: request.term,
                task: 'search',
            }),
            success: response,
            dataType: 'json',
        });

    },
    minLength: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.value = ui.item.id;
    }
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  var width = 50; // num of characters
  var broken_para = '';
  var pre_ind = 0;
  var ind = item.label.indexOf(' ', width);
  while(ind > 0){
    broken_para = broken_para + '<br>' + item.label.substring(pre_ind, ind);
    pre_ind = ind;
    ind = item.label.indexOf(' ', ind + width);
  }
  broken_para = broken_para + '<br>';

  return $( "<li>" )
    .append(broken_para)
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Here is a [useful link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered an easy solution:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').css('max-width','25%');
```